# Bootstrap line between Spans

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, border, markup

I need to have a 3-columns layout and to draw lines between them. 
The first I want is to draw simple line (1px black solid), the second - with using image background.

[Here is a live example for code below](http://jsfiddle.net/BhCu9/4/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">111 111 111</div>
    <div class="span4">222 222 222</div>
    <div class="span4">333 333 333</div>
</div>
```

Anybody could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was asked when Bootstrap 2 was popular.
Now Bootstrap 3 is the latest and it does not have such problem as gaps between cols.
Use Bootstrap 3!